# Java multithreading deadlock in Connection queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, deadlock

I wrote a small Java program to scrape info from a website. I basically download an excel file containing this month news ids and add them into the database in the query table. After that I start the scraping by requesting the pages with the previous ids as parameters, parse the page with jsoup and save the info into another table in the database.

Everything works as expected except for this `ConnectionManager` class

```
public class ConnectionManager {

public static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 50;

private ArrayList<Runnable> mActiveThreads = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
private ArrayList<Runnable> mQueuedRunnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

private static ConnectionManager instance;

//Singleton
public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        System.out.println("Started Connection mQueuedRunnables " + new Date());
        instance = new ConnectionManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

//Adds new Runnable to the queue
public void push(Runnable runnable) { 
    mQueuedRunnables.add(runnable);
    if (mActiveThreads.size() < MAX_CONNECTIONS)
        startNext();
}

//Starts a Thread with the next Runnable in the queue
private void startNext() {
    if (!mQueuedRunnables.isEmpty()) {
        Runnable next = mQueuedRunnables.get(0);
        mQueuedRunnables.remove(0);
        mActiveThreads.add(next);

        Thread thread = new Thread(next);
        thread.start();
    } else if (mActiveThreads.size() == MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
        System.out.println("FINISHED " + new Date());
    }
}

//Callback method called when a Thread finishes its execution,
//Runnable is removed from queue and startNext() called
public void didComplete(Runnable runnable) {
    synchronized(mActiveThreads) {
        mActiveThreads.remove(runnable);

        if (mActiveThreads.size() < MAX_CONNECTIONS)
            startNext();
    }
}
```

}

I `push()` all the `Runnables` for every connection I need to do, this is supposed to have 50 permanent running `Threads` until the queue empties. As you can see, it keeps two `Lists`: One for the queue and another for the active `Threads`. The `Runnables` I `push()` are just simple `Runnables` which make a `HttpURLConnection`, parse the `HTML` and insert the data into the database.

As far as I know this should work, but I suspect there is a deadlock somewhere because at some point the active `Threads` start dropping in numbers until it just stalls. I have been debugging the code and found that, while `mActiveThreads` keeps being 50, the real active `Threads` in the JVM keeps getting lower and lower.

The latest change I made is the `synchronized` block, but it doesn't seem to help at all. Can somebody point me out where is this code failing? Or how to find out by myself? I tried VisualVM and I could see `Threads` numbers dropping but could not figure out the reason why :-(

Comment: Have you tried having only 1 thread?

Comment: @AleZalazar Didn't try with only 1 thread but will try and report back. Usually it takes more than 50k connections for that ConnectionManager to stall. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Why don't you use a `BlockingQueue` to queue jobs and an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @fge because I am not familiar and I have been using this class for a long time without issues and it's simple and easy to modify if needed. As you can see, the problem was not with the threads or queue, so switching to those classes would not have helped.

Comment: @AleZalazar You put me in the right track. After testing with just 1 Thread I saw that it stopped at some point, debugging I discovered it was stopping some times at Socket.connect and other at Socket.read

Comment: I´m glad to have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out not to be related to multithreading at all. The problem was that some of the connections were not established and also that reading from InputStream failed at some points (I guess this is related to opening many concurrent connections).

Once I used setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() the problem went away. I also make each connection inside a 3 iterations loop, so in the case when the timeout is triggered the connection will be retried 2 more times.